# HTML SVG - load base64 string data to href of <image> or any workaround

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am trying to create an SVG orgchart and the get api returns json with each item (employee) having a property that is a base64 string representing an image

I want to load the base64 similar to non-svg <img> element with src="data:image/png;base64," but it doesn't seem to work with the svg element <image>

I also tried using <foreignObject> then appending <img> inside but it also does not work for base64, it only works when you have a url of the image.

I verified that the base64 string is good since when you right click the src and opened it in new tab, it actually loads the image in the new tab.

Comment: Please show us some code...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the possible misinformation. img tags inside foreign objects do allow base64 images with the data:image format but was being blocked by the Content Security Policy on my site.